# Is the "thunk" really needed here?

Tags: c++

I have started reading a blog on lazy evaluation. Here is a link to the blog
https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/04/21/getting-lazy-with-c/

I do not understand why the intermediate "thunk" methods are necessary in this code:

```
template<class T>
class Susp
{
    // thunk
    static T const & thunkForce(Susp * susp) {
        return susp->setMemo();
    }
    // thunk
    static T const & thunkGet(Susp * susp) {
        return susp->getMemo();
    }
    T const & getMemo() {
        return _memo;
    }
    T const & setMemo() {
        _memo = _f();
        _thunk = &thunkGet;
        return getMemo();
    }
public:
    explicit Susp(std::function<T()> f)
        : _f(f), _thunk(&thunkForce), _memo(T())
    {}
    T const & get() {
        return _thunk(this);
    }
private:
    T const & (*_thunk)(Susp *);
    mutable T   _memo;

    std::function<T()> _f;
};
```

The code can be refactored to work in the same way without them. So what is the idea behind this?

Comment: I don't see why they are necessary here either. `_thunk` just acts as a glorified boolean flag, selecting whether `getMemo` or `setMemo` should be called next. Maybe the idea is to avoid branching on the common code path (at the expense of an extra indirection, so I'm not sure it's a win).

Comment: i was just reading it quick, but the blog has a detailed explanation. As I understood it the code is rather to demonstrate the principle, so whether the same can be done differently is besides the point of the example

Comment: There's more than one way to do it, could be done with a simple bool variable named isMemoized as well.  Which is probably faster.  But certainly easier to understand, the bigger advantage.

Comment: I see! Thank you